# Python: how to import 32bit module for 64bit python

Tags: python, import, 32bit-64bit

Due to the system limits, I can only use a 64bit version Python, though, some of the modules that I intend to use do not come with a 64bit version (e.g. httplib2). In this case, what am I supposed to do so as to leverage those 32bit functions?

[image]

Thanks for the answer by j_mcnally. That works. Another approach that eventually works for me is to use the prefix parameter if there are multi-versions(e.g. 32/64) of python installed:

> python setup.py install --prefix = "your python root directory"

Comment: it seems that httplib2 is pure Python (no C extensions) i.e., there is no 32-64bit distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excuse my ignorance, but can't you compile them as 64 bit modules?

http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/

the source is there. I would image most modern ./configure scripts will detect your arch, and compile the appropriate extension.

the following seems to work for me:

`ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py install`

> running install running bdist_egg running egg_info writing
>
> python2/httplib2.egg-info/PKG-INFO writing top-level names to
>
> python2/httplib2.egg-info/top_level.txt writing dependency_links to
>
> python2/httplib2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt reading manifest file
>
> 'python2/httplib2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt' reading manifest template
>
> 'MANIFEST.in' writing manifest file
>
> 'python2/httplib2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt' installing library code to
>
> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg running install_lib running
>
> build_py creating build creating build/lib creating build/lib/httplib2
>
> copying python2/httplib2/**init**.py -> build/lib/httplib2 copying
>
> python2/httplib2/iri2uri.py -> build/lib/httplib2 copying
>
> python2/httplib2/socks.py -> build/lib/httplib2 copying
>
> python2/httplib2/cacerts.txt -> build/lib/httplib2 creating
>
> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-**x86_64** creating
>
> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-**x86_64**/egg creating

Comment: There's no other way, as far as I know

Comment: Thanks, but I have never build from source before, would you throw me a ref link? Is there a way to build a 64bit version from 32 by leveraging say, distutil? Just curious

Comment: u mean like binary packages? Depends on your Distribution, sometimes its as simple as adding a repo.

Comment: @j_mcnally [Download the httplib2 module](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/downloads/list) From here, and run 'python setup install', then it will install the 32bit module, how can I config so that a 64bit-compatible version can be installed? Since from the download page, it does not distinguish between 32bit and 64 bit. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

This guy has made a windows installer (see Base-12.9.15.win-amd64-py2.7.‌exe at the bottom) for  many, many modules used in scientific python.  Consider using it, if you're not comfortable compiling from source.

Comment: that's definitely a good practice, though, the system I am working on has many of the modules installed, I am in fear that by installing that, the overlapping ones of different versions will interfere with each other.

Comment: Which module is Base-12.9.15?